# If $Y_n$ is the largest number shown up to $n$-th throw, are $(Y_n)_n$ independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If a die is rolled repeatedly and $Y_n$ is the largest number shown up to $n$-th throw, are $Y_n$ independent ?

If I denote with $X_n$ the result of the $n$-th roll, then $Y_{n+1}=\max(X_{n+1},Y_n)$, for example when $Y_n=5$ then the probability that $Y_{n+1}=5$ is $5\cdot \frac16$ ($X_{n+1}$ can be any number form $1$ to $5$), in general $\Pr(Y_{n+1}=k|Y_n=k)=k\cdot\frac16$, but I have trouble to express $\Pr(Y_{n+1}=k\cap Y_n=k)$, intuitivley I would say that $Y_n$ depends on $Y_{n-1}$ or not  ? or can I conclude from the fact $X_n$ are dependent, $Y_n$ should be also ?

Comment: The probabilities $P(Y_2 = 2) = \frac{1}{12}$ and $P(Y_2 = 2\mid Y_1 = 4) = 0$ are not equal. This suggests very strongly that they are _not_ independent.

Comment: Use the relation $P(A|B)= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$. to calculate $P(Y_{n+1} = k \cap Y_n = k)$

Comment: @Arthur Of course I didn't consider that case, but is my last sentence true ?

Comment: @ketum The $X_n$ are independent of one another (if that's what you meant). You therefore cannot conclude anything from the fact that they are dependent, since that's false.

Comment: @Arthur Please replace "suggests very strongly" by "proves". :-)

Comment: @Did It's been 50 minutes, someone like you should know comments cannot be edited by then :P Besides, I don't know what the explicit definition of "independent" in the OP's book. While my comment does indeed prove independence if it's defined as $P(A) = P(A\mid B)$, it might be given as $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$ (it would have to be if independence is introduced before conditional probability, which has been the case in some high school text books I've seen). In that case, a small argument needs to follow my comment.